Why are matrix-secrets used on lattice based signatures?
I was wondering why in the Fiat-Shamir with aborts paradigm on lattices such Lyuba12, matrices S and E are used to generate the public key ($AS + E = B$ or $AS = B$).
And not just vectors like on Dillithium, since the security of these schemes is evaluated in this way ($As + e = b$).

Can you include a citation/link to the precise paper of Lyubashevesky you have a question regarding?
